# How can I show different content when JavaScript is disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to show COMPLETELY different content when JavaScript is disabled. I know I can use `<noscript>` tag... but how can I hide the rest of the page when JavaScript is disabled?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

here is another solution:

inside your head below your normal stylesheet have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jsdisabled.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="jsenabled.css" />');
</script>
```

that jsenabled.css would have:

```
#content { display:block; }
```

while jsdisabled.css would have:

```
#content { display:none; }
```

**although the solution below works it does not validate**

inside your noscript tag you can put some style tag that hides the rest of your content

ie:

```
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
        #content { display:none; }
    </style>
    no js content goes here.
</noscript>

<div id="content">
    content here.
</div>
```

I like using this method because it doesn't make the page flash when javascript is enabled.

Comment: The problem with this method is your pages won't validate. `style` is not a valid element inside a `noscript` tag.

Comment: It however wonderfully works in all browsers from IE6 and up, including the oh so w3 strict Opera. I have also used it several times.

Answer (score 10):

I would not use `noscript` to show alternate content. For one, only a limited number of tags are valid in a `<noscript>` tag, and `<style>` is not one of them. Instead, take a different approach. Have your content when javascript is *disabled* visible by default, and show alternate content when JavaScript is *enabled*. The best way to do this is with simple CSS and one line of JS. If you do it as I show here, there should not be an awkward flash of content:

```
  <head>
     ...
     <script type="text/javascript"> document.documentElement.className += " js"</script>
     <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="header" class="no_js">header</div>
     <div id="alt_header" class="js">header</div>

     .. etc ..
     <div id="super_duper" class="js">Whatever</div>
  </body>
```

Just apply `js` to everything that should show when JavaScript is enabled, and `no_js` to everything else. Then in your CSS put this:

```
html.js .no_js, html .js { display: none }
html.js .js { display: block }
```

Comment: i agree that this would be a more valid way to do it.  this is what i used to do, but the higher-ups don't like when the page is blank then appears when the javascript loads.

Comment: @John, this doesn't have that problem. It is set to visible prior to the page displaying. Seriously, it works like a charm and you never see the non-javascript content. The line that adds the class runs before the CSS loads. And the CSS loads before the page displays. The result is not delayed, and the change is instant.

Comment: maybe i was doing something wrong a couple hears ago when this was implemented.  I've changed my answer a little, still leaving in the invalid code but noting it and adding a different solution.

Answer (score 4):

Use meta tags to redirect to a different page.

`<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=enable_javascript.php">
</noscript>`

Answer (score 2):

You could use Javascript to switch to a different page containing Javascript.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    location = "JSEnabled.html";
</script>

Non-javascript content goes here
```

Answer (score 1):

All the above are fine, I believe.
Just an alternative, you can try this,

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
//if javascript enabled
window.onload=function(){
 document.getElementById('jsContentWrapper').style.display='block';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='jsContentWrapper' style='display:none;'>
 ---
 --
 -
</div>
<noscript>
   Place your javascript disabled content here
</noscript>
</body>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a div tag with the id of content. Add the content you want displayed when javascript is disabled. Use jquery `$("#content ").load("content.html")` to load content if javascript is enabled.