# Should I avoid tags unsupported in HTML5 if I am using XHTML 4.01 Strict?

Tags: html, xhtml

These elements are not supported in HTML5 but are supported in XHTML:

`acronym`, `big`, `tt`

In the future, when I will change my document type to HTML5, then will I not need to replace or change any code to pass validation?

This is also accepted as valid code in an attempt to ease the pain for avid XHTML coders (like myself) who are used to self-closing elements:

```
<tag type="type" id="name"/>
```

The same rules apply to `<meta>` and other self-closing elements.

Is it a good idea to avoid HTML5 unsupported tags, If I am using XHTML 1.0 Strict now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would be a good idea to plan ahead for HTML5 support. [Check here](http://www.html-5.com/avoid/) for a list of deprecated tags and attributes to avoid.

As far as XHTML *syntax* (always closing tags, self closing tags, etc) you can continue to use that without worry. HTML5 can be written using standard HTML syntax or XHTML syntax, though it always remains just HTML.

Comment: but one thing which i wanted use which is not supported in HTML 5 is <noscript?

Comment: I rarely if ever use JS. I work the other way around. See here for my method of handling non JS content: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233771/how-can-i-show-different-content-when-javascript-is-disabled/2234062#2234062