# CSS Stylings Tips

Tags: css

I have a web page that is was optimized mostly for IE and Chrome. I am trying to figure out tips on how I should display this image since it looks quite awful just sitting above the copyright on all my webpages. I am looking for any CSS tips on how I can make the highlighted portion of this web page have a more professional look to it. All suggestion are greatly appreciated!

```
<p class="clearfix">
    This page is optimized for Internet Explorer and Chrome.  To ensure accurate processing of your mail packet, please ensure JavaScript is enabled in your browser.

</p>
```

[image]

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming but is about design, StackOverflow is not the right place for that. Try the [user experience SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) instead, maybe. Don't forget to read their help center and stuff.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another Stack Overflow site.

Comment: I post it on another one and they told me to post it here =/ sorry

Comment: the link above your comment

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest doing is center the copyright info. Then create two separate CSS files. One that will be used if the user doesn't have javascript enabled and the other if they do. The text you have ("This page is optimized for..") should be in the CSS file where javascript is disabled(Also move that text to the top of the page and center it). 
How do you check to see if they have javascript enabled? do this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jsdisabled.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="jsenabled.css" />');
</script>
```

"although the solution below works it does not validate

inside your noscript tag you can put some style tag that hides the rest of your content. "
***no script option ***

```
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
        #content { display:none; }
    </style>
    no js content goes here.
</noscript>
```

[How can I show different content when JavaScript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233771/how-can-i-show-different-content-when-javascript-is-disabled)

This way that text won't appear for everyone, just the people who don't have javascript enabled.

Comment: `<noscript>` is probably a lot faster/better than this, although it "doesn't validate" because it doesn't trigger another file download from the browser.

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right. The link I provided actually shows an example of that as well.

Comment: I added the example of noscript to my answer

Comment: You took the content out of the HTML, right? And the only place it shows it is in the noscript section?

Comment: yes but when I take the javascript off it does not fire still shows content instead

Comment: do u know how to do just the red banner like stack overflow has?

Comment: Wait what? It's suppose to show the content when you take the javascript off. Can you please put your html on here? What red banner? Lets focus on one question at a time.